# Как определить максимальное количество полей в строке, перебрав тысячи строк?

Tags: php

Необходимо определить максимальное количество полей в строке, проблема в том, что строк может быть сотни тысяч.

Пример:

поле, поле2, поле 3

поле, поле2, поле 3

поле, поле2, поле 3, поле4, поле5

поле, поле2, поле 3

поле, поле2

**Как получить число 5?**

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters, $string) {
   $ready  = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
   $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
   return $launch;
}

$fp = @fopen("uploads/$name", "r");

if ($fp) {

while (($text = fgetcsv($fp, 4096)) !== false) {

$i++;

$text = str_replace('"', '', $text);

$exploded = multiexplode (array(",", ";", "|"), $text);

///

}
```

Как дальше не знаю, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: К наименованию полей есть требования/ограничения? И разделитель может быть только запятой?

Comment: Ну у вас код то уже написан, на сколько он производительный, это уже другой вопрос. Но, вроде вам осталось вне цикла (перед ним) создать переменную `$counter = 0` допустим и заместо `///` написать примерно следующее: `if ($counter < count($exploded)) { $counter = count($exploded); }`. Далее, за циклом соответственно, получите переменную `$counter` с макс. кол-вом полей. З.Ы. Естественно, два раза `count` делать не стоит, код для примера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Полностью рабочий код для всех разделителей, но без парсинга самого csv.**

```
<?php

$fieldCounter = 0;
foreach ([
    'поле, поле2, поле 3',
    'поле, поле2, поле 3, поле 3',
    'поле, поле2, поле 3, поле 3, поле 3',
    'поле, поле2, поле 3, поле 3, поле 3, поле 3, поле 3',
    'поле; поле2; поле 3; поле 3; поле 3; поле 3; поле 3; поле 3',
    'поле| поле2| поле 3| поле 3| поле 3| поле 3| поле 3| поле 3| поле 3',
    'поле, поле2, поле 3, поле 3, поле 3',
    'поле, поле2, поле 3, поле 3',
    'поле, поле2, поле 3',
] as $line) {
    $tmpCounter = (
        substr_count($line, ',')
            ?: substr_count($line, ';')
                ?: substr_count($line, '|')
    ) + 1;
    
    if ($fieldCounter < $tmpCounter) {
        $fieldCounter = $tmpCounter;
    }
}

var_dump($fieldCounter); // 9
```

Comment: Спасибо! Разбираюсь, пока не считает, 0 отдает. По поводу разделителя из первого комментария, разделитель может быть , ; и |

Comment: Warning: substr_count() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in в строке $tmpCounter = substr_count($line, ',');

Comment: Вот в песочнице написал для вас тот же пример, но без парсинга самого csv. В цикл уходят уже просто строки (7 - полей через `,`, 8 - полей через `;` и 9 - полей через `|`), полностью рабочий код, работает через все разделители: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/1f022

Comment: Borislav, большое спасибо!